# Easiest way to display text in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm creating a simple Breakout style game and would like a simple way to display the score.

I've been doing some research and found several ways to do text in OpenGL ES, but most methods look fairly complicated.

[This](https://shiningdevelopers.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/convoluted-way-to-turn-nsstring-to-glktextureinfo/) looks like it would do the trick, but I couldn't get it to work.

I've looked into FTGL and FreeType, but they look complicated.

I've also read one can display a UILabel over the EAGLContext, but not sure how that would be in the performance department.

I could probably get any of these options to work, I'm just wondering what the best solution is for this situation.

Comment: The PowerVR SDK has a very good implementation in a C++ class named PVRTPrint3D that is ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

For simple use cases like you're describing, on even vaguely modern hardware (i.e. iPhone 3GS and later, I think), the compositing penalty for layering UIKit/CoreAnimation content on top of OpenGL ES content is negligible. (You can see this if you run your app in Instruments with the "Color OpenGL ES fast path blue" option turned on.)

They say premature optimization is the root of all evil — it's pretty easy to try `UILabel`, see if it makes a significant difference to your app's performance, and look into third-party libraries and more complicated solutions only if it does.

(Also, it sounds like you might be trying to manage your own `CAEAGLLayer`. For common use cases, it's a lot easier to use `GLKView`, plus `GLKViewController` for animation.)

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend checking out the Print3D functionality of the PowerVR SDK's PVRTools framework. Print3D is free to use, cross-platform (iOS, Android, Linux, Windows, OS X etc.) and it efficiently renders text within OpenGL ES 1.x, 2.0 & 3.0 applications. The SDK includes an example application with source that demonstrates how to use the Print3D framework (IntroducingPrint3D).

The PowerVR Graphics SDK can be downloaded for free from Imagination's website: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp

An overview of the source included in the SDK can be found here: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/learn_more.asp